# Regular Expression to find a string included between 3 brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Could give a hand with [this regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%7B%7B%7B%28.*%3F%29%5C%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A&i=%7B%7B%7Btest1%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7Btest2%7D%7D%0D%0A%7Btest3%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B%7B%7Btest4%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B%7Btest5%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B.%7B%7B%7Btest6%7D%7D%7D)?

```
\{{{(.*?)\}}}
```

It matches

```
{{{test1}}}
{{{{test4}}}
{{{test5}}}
```

I would like to match only `{{{test1}}}` and `{{{test5}}}`. There must be only 3 brackets on the left and right no, so `{{{{test4}}}` should be INVALID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to restrict the delimiters with lookarounds:

```
(?<!{){{{(?!{)(.*?)(?<!})}}}(?!})
^^^^^^    ^^^^      ^^^^^   ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%7B%29%7B%7B%7B%28%3F!%7B%29%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%3C!%7D%29%7D%7D%7D%28%3F!%7D%29%0D%0A&i=%7B%7B%7Btest1%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7Btest2%7D%7D%0D%0A%7Btest3%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B%7B%7Btest4%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B%7Btest5%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B.%7B%7B%7Btest6%7D%7D%7D)

The `(?<!{)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `{` immediately to the left of the current location and `(?!{)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match immediately to the right of the current location. Similar constructs are used to set the context for the `}}}` trailing delimiter.

**To exclude matching `{{{....}}}` substrings that contain *either* `{` or `}`**, you need to replace the `.*?` (lazy dot matching pattern) with a *negated character class `[^{}]*` that will also make the `(?!{)` and `(?<!{)` lookarounds redundant in the above regex:

```
(?<!{){{{([^{}]*)}}}(?!})
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%7B%29%7B%7B%7B%28%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*%29%7D%7D%7D%28%3F!%7D%29%0D%0A&i=%7B%7B%7Btest1%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7Btest2%7D%7D%0D%0A%7Btest3%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B%7B%7Btest4%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B%7Btest5%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B%7Btest%7B6%7Dhere%7D%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7B.%7B%7B%7Btest6%7D%7D%7D), where `{{{test{6}here}}}` is not matched.

Usage to extract the values in between `{{{` and `}}}`:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!{){{{([^{}]*)}}}(?!})")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Note that it will match something like `{{{t{est}}}` as well. @stej4n's answer doesn't have that flaw.

Comment: It was just a note. I don't know what the OP really needs.

Comment: I added some more on that then. It is just an additional tweak to the overall lookaround restriction concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one : `(?<!{){{3}[^{}]*}{3}(?!})`

**Explanation**

`{{3}` starts with a **{** 3 times exactly

`[^{}]*` any character **except** { or }

`}{3}` ends with **}** 3 times exactly

Surrounded by negative lookbehind `(?<!{)` and negative lookahead `(?!})` to make sure that the immediate preceding character will not be { and that the next immediate character will not be }